Remove time from dates
is there a way to remove from a date like this: 16FEB2019:00:00:00 the following: :00:00:00 to have finally 16FEB2019?
I have 30844 rows for the variable "Date" with dates like the one I reported as example.
Thank you in advance,
Best

If your date is being stored as date values you can use datepart and then format it:
Date_Value = input(Date, anydtdte.);
    
Date_Only = datepart(Date_Value);
    
format Date_Only date9.; /* Apply a date format */

If your date is being stored as a string you can use Substring to remove the date part:
data new_data;
  date_new = substr(date, 1, 8);
run;

Or you could use informat to reformat the date:
data new_data;
  date_new = date;
  format date_new YYMMDD;
run;


Thank you very much for your help. It gives me an output like 12345667, i.e., numbers instead of a date.
